# Finding length of an object in angularjs without using a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html content is as follows:

```
<span>{{queries['q1_name'].parameters.length}}</span> <!--Not working: Doesn't show length of parameters-->
```

My javascript object is as follows:

```
$scope.queries = {"q1_name":
                   {"parameters":
                     {"P1":"abc" }
                   }
                 }
```

This could be done by creating a function, but I am trying to get the length directly in html.

Comment: *"My javascript object is as follows"* No, it isn't. What you've shown there is a syntax error as of the `{` before `"P2"`.

Comment: As of the edit, the question makes even less sense, not least because `queries` has no property `0`.

Answer (score 0):

your object should've been: I'm assuming you will be having more than one items in queries since you were using queries[0].parameters.length. if not then you can take out the outer most square brackets.

```
$scope.queries = [{"parameters":
                     [{"P1":"abc" },{"P2":"xyz" }]
                   },{"parameters":
                     [{"P1":"bcd" },{"P2":"jfk" }]
                   }];
```

if "q1_name" is a must have then you need to use queries[0].q1_name.parameters.length. but with this method all of your objects in the array needs to have "q1_name" as property for the code to work on all element in the array.

```
$scope.queries = [{"q1_name":
                   {"parameters":
                     [{"P1":"abc" },{"P2":"xyz" }]
                   }
                 }]
```

Hope that helps.